# Импорт библиотеки JAXB в проект JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-ee, jaxb

Есть проект на JavaFX, для хранения данных нужно использовать сериализацию в JAXB. Для этого нужно использовать XML. Но я не могу подключить библиотеку к проекту.

Скачал и добавил библиотеку в проект. Но IntellijIDEA все также не видит эту библиотеку. В проекте используется java 10. Как заставить ее работать?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Добавьте инфо о том, что используете Java 10, а так же укажите систему сборки. Будет более понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте модуль в параметры компилятора
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]